# How can I make a rectangular pulse in microseconds for audio in c#?

Tags: c#

As the title, I'm trying to make a rectangular pulse for audio in c#, but in microseconds. Like this:

[Image - Pulse of 100us and signal rate of 10Hz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ny78n.png)

I was searching some libraries and I found function "beep", but I see that only uses miliseconds.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Have a look at NAudio http://markheath.net/category/naudio   https://www.nuget.org/packages/NAudio/

Comment: Hi!, I have been doing some codes with NAudio, but there I only get sine functions.